# Using Selenium to collect every option on Javascript dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, selenium, web-crawler

I'm trying to collect the URLs of all possible versions of [this page](https://www.athletic.net/TrackAndField/Division/Event.aspx?DivID=89120&Event=1) (all combinations of Level, Event, and Season) using Selenium. I've been successful using `driver.find_elements_by_xpath` to navigate to the correct option and click it before saving the URL, but this has been very slow and I'm wondering if there's a better alternative.

There doesn't seem to be any `href` attribute I can steal the link from without clicking on the actual option. Using the `Select` class and trying to loop through the options is cleaner, but I still have to generate the `Select` object every time - trying to do this:

```
s = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Level')]/../select"))
for option in s.options:
    option.click()
```

works for the first option, but then gives me the error `stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`. I'm stumped - is there a better way to collect these links? Below is my snippet of code:

```
driver.get("https://athletic.net/TrackAndField/Division/Event.aspx?DivID=89120&Event=1")
for i in range(0, len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Level')]/../select/option"))):
    driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Level')]/../select/option")[i].click()
    for j in range(0, len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//optgroup//option[contains(text(), 'Meters')]"))):
        driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//optgroup//option[contains(text(), 'Meters')]")[j].click()
        for k in range(0, len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Season')]/..//option[contains(text(), 'Indoor')]/../option"))):
            driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Season')]/..//option[contains(text(), 'Indoor')]/../option")[k].click()
            for l in range(0, len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Season')]/..//option[contains(text(), '2018')]/../option"))):
                driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//label[contains(text(), 'Season')]/..//option[contains(text(), '2018')]/../option")[l].click()
                with open("links.txt", 'a+') as f:
                    f.write(driver.current_url + ";")
```

Comment: instead of clicking on every possible combination just grab every "value" in the option tag for each level. the DivID is just the location value `<option value="12345">` the event is the same thing.

Comment: Thanks! But as I mentioned in my comment to @GPT14, the DivID also seems to change whenever I modify the Level or Season - these menus do not store the DivID as an attribute in each `option`. I'm not sure how to figure out what the DivID would be if I clicked on one of these options without actually clicking on it.

Answer (score 1):

The URL is a combination of the `Location` identified by the 'DivID' and the `Event` identified by the 'Event'.

So you can use `find_elements_by_xpath`(plural) to find all the `options` for both the drop-down lists
then using list comprehension extract the `value` attribute from each `option`

```
location_option_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@ng-model='appC.locationDivId']/option")
location_values = [location_option.get_attribute('value') for location_option in location_option_list]

event_option_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//select[@ng-model='appC.params.eventId']//option")
event_values = [event_option.get_attribute('value') for event_option in event_option_list]

urls = ""
for location_value in location_values:
    for event_value in event_values:
        urls += "https://www.athletic.net/TrackAndField/Division/Event.aspx?DivID=%s&Event=%s;" \
                % (location_value, event_value)
```

The above code would only work for '*High School*' and '*Middle School*' levels LEVELS.
You can easily modify it to handle '*Youth Clubs*' and '*College*' LEVELS

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful! However, choosing different options for the "Level" and "Season" menus also seems to change the DivID to values that are not accessible in the `value`s for each `option`. Level seems to assign powers of 2 for the `value`, while Season assigns the year to each `value`. How can I use these `value` attributes to determine what the DivID would be if I clicked on them?

Comment: @kreesh :You basically have to loop the code snippet for all combinations of Levels and seasons. Create a list of the urls that get generated, and convert this list to a set so that you get only the unique urls. Create a new question with your code if you get stuck, I would be happy to take a look.